# Recording with AVCaptureSession in iPhone 5 screen display

Tags: iphone, iphone-5, avcapturesession, video-recording, video-player

In my application for recording I am using AVCaptureSession with `sessionPreset` is `AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium.`

I have set  `contentsGravity` is `kCAGravityResizeAspectFill`

I have set my recording view's size is **320 X 568**.
When i play that recorded video in `MPMoviePlayerController` I am getting video size is **360 X 480**.

So its showing black bar on top and bottom in iPhone 5 screen.

IF I set `scalingMode` is `MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill` than its fill the screen size, but seems little bit blur.

On iPhone 4/4s (in 3.5" screen)

With recording view's size is 320 X 480.

Its working perfect without set `scalingMode` while play that recorded video.

Can any one help me that If I am missing to set any property either on recording time or at playing time.

IS this default behaviour or can i fix this ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium is used camera resolution of 360.000000 and 480.000000.
It's a default resolution for AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium, so it'll not work for iPhone-5 display.

It's not updated for iPhone-5(4-inch) display resolution. If you want to get higher resolution image on iPhone-5, you should use AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh. but it'll provide you image resolution of 1980 * 1080. so it'll work fine but will increase size bytes of images.

Also you can check by this:

```
AVCaptureSession *newCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];    

 if (IS_IPHONE5) 
{          
           newCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh; 
}
else
        {
       newCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

        }
```